# childNodes[loop].text returns "undefined" in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, google-chrome

I have a jsp where a dropdown list of sub-businesses get loaded *after* the user selects a business from the Business dropdown list. The code works fine in IE 7 but goes to hell in Chrome and probably the higher versions of IE. The code is as follows (Sorry for such long code)

JSP

```
<fieldset> <table>
<tr>
<td class="tdlabel">
Business
</td><td>
     <select name="business" onchange="javascript:fetchSubBusiness_Ajax(this.form.business);">
       <option value="">
       --select--
       </option>
<logic:iterate id="elementz" name="visaFields" property="gebiz">
       <option value="<bean:write name="elementz"></bean:write>">
       <bean:write name="elementz"></bean:write>
       </option>
</logic:iterate>
      </select>
 </td>
 <td class="tdlabel">
 Sub-Business
 </td><td>
      <select name="subbusiness">
      <option value="">
      --select--
      </option>
      </select>
  </td>
  </tr>
```

Javascript

```
function fetchSubBusiness_Ajax(val){
 if(val != -1)
{

            var myindex  = val.selectedIndex;
            var selValue = val.options[myindex].value;


            business = selValue;
    var url = "visa_fetchsubbusiness.do?business=" +business;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        try
        {
            req.open("GET",url,true);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert(e);
        }

        req.onreadystatechange = processfetchsubbusiness;
        req.send(null);
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if (req)
        {

            req.open("GET", url, true);
            req.onreadystatechange = processfetchsubbusiness;
            req.send(null);
        }
    }
}



}

function processfetchsubbusiness ()
{
    if (req.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (req.status == 200)
{
      try{
        var responseXML = req.responseXML;
        var parents = responseXML.getElementsByTagName("subbusiness")[0];
        alert("parents " +parents.text);
        var child;
        var subbussiness;

while (document.forms[0].subbusiness.length> 1) {
document.forms[0].subbusiness.remove(1);
}

document.forms[0].subbusiness.options[0]=new Option("--select--","--select--");
        for (var loop = 0; loop < parents.childNodes.length; loop++)
        {
                child = parents.childNodes[loop];
                subbussiness = child.text;
                alert("subbussiness = " +subbussiness);



                                    var opt = new Option(subbussiness,subbussiness);
                                    document.forms[0].subbusiness.options[loop+1] = opt;

                }
                }catch(e){

                alert("Exception in Fetching the Sub Business for the selected Business");


             }
    }
}
}
```

In the alert

```
alert("subbussiness = " +subbussiness);
```

I get subbussiness = *undefined*. Same for the options in the second select menu.

Could anyone please tell me why I get the *undefined* value in Chrome?

Comment: It would appear that one or more of your child objects do not have the "text" attribute. Could you please throw in a console.log(child) and give us the output in your chrome inspector?
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: why is this tagged with jquery?

Comment: @JonathanCrowe It showed  <gesubbiz>Sub-Biz 1</gesubbiz>  <gesubbiz>Sub-Biz 2</gesubbiz>  <gesubbiz>Sub-Biz 3</gesubbiz>

Comment: which of these attributes are you trying to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this is tagged as jquery you should be able to get this working like this:

instead of

```
subbussiness = child.text;
```

use:

```
subbussiness = $(child).text();
```

This will create the xml element "child" and access the text value